# I need to run custom processes with crontabs

Tags: cron

I need to run custom processes with cron-tabs, every 15 days but varying the day, for example

```
00 18 */15 * 4
00 1 */15 * 1
```

The days are never fixed, they always vary, is this possible?
Thank you

Comment: Could you clarify your question by adding more detail? For example terms like "day of month" or "weekday" could help in this case.

Comment: Related, if not almost a duplicate - [Is it possible to schedule a cron job to run fortnightly?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/197324/100397) In your case you'd calculate _days_ since the epoch _modulo 15_, rather than weeks modulo 2 as in the answers there

Comment: Note also (unrelated to my previous comment) that if you want to run your job on days 1 and 16 of every month, i.e. _approximately_ every 15 days, that's a much easier question to answer

Answer (score 0):

[anacron](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/anacrontab.5.html) is specifically for this type of usage.

```
15 0 mycustomjob /runmystuff.sh
```

Though getting it to run at a specific time of the day every 15 days might take a little work. You can specify a delay but there is no guarantee of what time the job will start.

Other than that, as suggested in the other comments you can run a script every hour or whatever in regular cron that then does the work of figuring out if it should run the real job or not. For example you could check the value of `date +%s -d "-15 days"` against when the job was last run. Or of course anything else you need.